# Formula not updating

Tags: excel-formula

The usual answer to this question is to turn formulas to automatic. This, in my case, is not working.

The second usual answer is that there is some macro that is affecting the Excel settings. This is not the case with my problem (xlsx file).

Office 2010, my simple formula is not updating.

P.S. I copied the problem of Mr. DAN, however, the CTRL SHIFT ALT F9 worked for him but not for me so I only added the CTRL SHIFT ALT F9 in what I've already tried.

I have:

Researched this issue on the internet - all solutions easy to find do not address this problem

Pressed F9 (did nothing)

Pressed Shift-F9 (did nothing)

Pressed Ctrl-Shift-Alt-F9 (did nothing)

Pressed Ctrl-Alt-F9 (did nothing)

Turned calculation to manual and hit all combinations of F9 (did nothing)

Turned calculation back to automatic (did nothing)

Saved with a new name (did nothing)

Re-updated data on MainCopy (did nothing)

Selected the cell and hit F9 (did nothing)

Put my cursor in the box and hit enter (UPDATED VALUE CORRECTLY)

I cannot put my cursor in each box and hit enter, there are too many boxes. In
addition, this is creating a major error trap in a spreadsheet that needs to be correct. Is there some obscure setting that has been triggered in this file that is creating this issue?

The formula is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(T15:T26<>""),T15:T26)
```

Everything else is updating in the spreadsheet. The cell in MainCopy has the correct value. The value displayed is the value before I updated the information on MainCopy. When I put new information in MainCopy, the value on this page stayed the same.

I expect the output to get value of last non-empty cell.

Comment: Can you provide an screenshot of the data, please? I’d say the formula is wrong or you have a circular reference.

Comment: Hi Yumi have you tried the methods on this page yet? [Excel doesn't update value unless I hit Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293828/excel-doesnt-update-value-unless-i-hit-enter)

Comment: Have you tried "Menu/Formula/Calculate Now" ?