# VBA Refreshing Table After Adding Formula to Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I wrote some VBA code that adds a column to a table with a specific name ('test' in this case) and creates a sheet with that specific name (also 'test').

The 'test' table column then has its cells populate from the following VBA line.

```
Sheets("Data (HIDE)").ListObjects("DataTable").ListColumns(Range("B2").Value).DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6,'" & Range("B2").Value & "'!$A$2:$B$1500,2,FALSE),"""")"
```

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]

The issue happens when I go to the 'test' sheet and populate it with values to be looked up on this table. I populate the 'test' sheet with data and go back to this table only to find that the VLOOKUP formula doesn't calculate for all rows until I double-click on a cell containing the VLOOKUP formula and press ENTER.

Is there a way in VBA to make it so that I don't have to manually click on the table to cause the VLOOKUP formulas to refresh/recalculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`Range.Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.calculate), and sometimes if that is not enough, combine it with [`Range.Dirty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.dirty)

In your case

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data (HIDE)")
    With .ListObjects("DataTable").ListColumns(.Range("B2").Value).DataBodyRange
        'Sometimes depending on whether formulas are volatile and their interdependencies:
        .Cells.Dirty

        'To recalculate all the cells of the ListObject:
        .Cells.Calculate

        'To recalculate only one:
        .Cells(1).Calculate
    End With
End With
```

Edit:

It seems like this doesn't always work, I'll quote the solution from OPs comment for easier future reference:

Solution by [@Buracku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10382803) as per comment to this post:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data (HIDE)")
    With .ListObjects("DataTable").ListColumns(.Range("B2").Value).DataBodyRange
        .Cells.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, _
                       SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:= False, _
                       FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, although that didn't work. After hours of troubleshooting to no avail, it sounds like an issue with Excel and populating cells with formulas through VBA.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39153031/10382803

Used the following VBA to get it to FINALLY work.

Cells.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:= _
        False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

May be kind of hacky, but for my use case it works :)